# Digitize old board games

Tags: game-development

I'm thinking about digitizing some really old and abandoned board games (similar to [Monopoly](http://www.hcpl.net/sites/default/files/board%20game.jpg)) so that I can preserve them for the future and play them on my computer.

Such board games generally include:

- Game board
- Stackable playing cards
- Tokens
- Dices

Operating System or cost of the program is not important. This would probably be an open source tool and not a commercial one.

Some programming and a lot of configuration would be necessary, but if there is a framework lots of time would be saved as compared to programming everything from scratch.

Is there any software available for this purpose? Haven't been able to find anything online.

Comment: May it require programming skills? May it cost something? For which operating system? Does the end result have to be playable without the software? If yes, on which operating system(s)?

Comment: @unor: OS or cost of the program is not important. This would probably be an open source tool and not a commercial one. Some programming and a lot of configuration would be necessary, but if there is a framework lots of time would be saved as compared to programming everything from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.  This is exactly the software framework that you are looking for:  http://www.vassalengine.org/

Comment: Can you expand a bit why it addresses the criteria needed by the OP?

Comment: Here's what Vassal is, according to that link: "Vassal is a game engine for building and playing online adaptations of board games and card games. Play live on the Internet or by email. Vassal runs on all platforms, and is free, open-source software."  So you would need software programming skills as well as permission from the copyright holder, which you'll probably never get (even if it's "just to play at home and not sell", it doesn't matter).